# Entity Framework dynamic type mapping

Tags: entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework 5 Code First approach and need to find a way to map a type that I create dynamically at runtime to a table so that it becomes a part of a model.

The problem I am trying to resolve is as follows. I have two tables A and B. A has a single column "Name". Table A is storing names for columns in table B. Whenever a row is added to table A a trigger adds a column to table B. Based on data from table A I can build a type in runtime to represent table B. My problem is I would like EF work with my type and table B. I can't find a way to map my type to table B.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that fit in your problem, but take a look in this post '[Dynamically building a model with code first](http://romiller.com/2012/03/26/dynamically-building-a-model-with-code-first/)'.

But my real advice is that you change your schema... Make a table that has a column with a xml type and create some class that can be serialized and deserialized so that you can save and retrieve the xml and load the objects. Or even, take a look in a NoSQL database.